# Why does radix sort divides it's elements though it is not a Stable Sort?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures, radix

Radix sort is not considered as a type of Stable Sort.

But why does like any other Stable Sorting it groups or divides it's elements?

Comment: I thought radix sort _was_ stable. Are you talking about a special variant or something?

Comment: If you use the standard radix sort on the least significant bit it is stable. Radix on MSD is not necessarily stable. You can look up wikipedia

Answer (score 1):

I think you are getting confused between the concepts :

**First**, Radix-sort *divide and group* because it works on `divide and conquer` technique.

**Second**, Stable Sorting has nothing to do with divide and grouping, Stability of a sorting algorithm simply means that the ***relative ordering*** of elements with same keys will remain same ***before and after*** the sorting.

Hope it will help.